# How can I use a ExecutorService in Java (One pool Executors.newFixedThreadPool() or several Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())

Tags: java, executorservice

How best to use executorService, given that method someMethod() is called several times:

I'm using now:

```
    public void someMethod() {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future future = executorService.submit(() -> method());
    }
```

or should I use it like this

```
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);

    public void someMethod() {
        Future future = executorService.submit(() -> method());
    }
```

Comment: What is your goal? What do you want to archive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creation of thread pool executor is a costly operation, also you need to stop thread pools when they are not needed (or it will prevent JVM from exiting).

So second option is more preferable.

The only disadvantage of having a shared thead pool is that some other code might submit long running tasks and your tasks submitted in `someMethod()` might need to wait for free worker threads.